# Eclipse Android Layout: Without dp-values?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

If I want to have a Picture in the Center of my layout, I easily use: "Center Vertically" and "Center Horizontally". But now I want a picture to have it in the Center of the left side. But I don't want to use marginLeft=..dp. I want to work without dp. Is there a possibility like "Center Vertically" etc? Here is the code with dp-values. What can I use instead of MarginLeft"38dp"?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rosezwei" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`?

Comment: You mean like the edited post above?

Comment: Yeah. Does that not work?

Comment: No, The pic stays in the Center of the layout...

Comment: Sorry, read the question wrong. Maybe explain more precisely what you want. You want it not centered horizontally so, and you don't want to use "dp" whatever that means, so what _do_ you want? I mean, if you don't want a margin, just don't use a margin.

Comment: I want to have it like in the code (I edited it again) but wihtout using dp-values.

Comment: And using **what** instead?

Comment: S.th. like android:layout_centerInParent="true". Or is there not such a command?

Comment: Yes, there is, like I said, but that centres also horizontally, which you don't want as you said. I'm very confused now, maybe somebody else can help.

Comment: Sorry You are right!!! I made a mistake

Comment: Are you saying you want the image horizontally centered within the left to horizontal center of your parent RelativeLayout?  In other words, if you divided your parent RelativeLayout into two equal width columns, do you want your image to be centered within the left column?

Comment: `Is there a possibility like "Center Vertically"` is **android:layout_centerVertical="true"**

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

Will work inside a LinearLayout view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/rosezwei" />

</LinearLayout >
```

Note that the LinearLayout is horizontal, so views can choose its VERTICAL position.

Comment: I replaced "android:layout_centerInParent="true"" and "android:layout_marginLeft="41dp" through your code, but it didn't help. Or made I s.th wrong?

Comment: Well, that was the solution, maybe relative layout dont accept gravity parameters, can you try using FrameLayout instead?

Comment: No that doesn't work. The pic is not in the Center of the left side, but directly on the margin.

Comment: It is at the 0,0 (top-left) or just left-center?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want the image center at 25% of your screen width...
Alas Android has no percentage in XML, to do that you must use a `LinearLayout` to split your screen

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight=".5"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:src="@drawable/rosezwei" />
   <Space
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight=".5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```